Google says that there is an error in the "Canonical Tag"
I have had the problem for a long time that Google does not index my site.
My website only consists of one page (index.php)
Google says that there is an error in the "Canonical Tag", the error message is:
Duplicate - not set as canonical by the user
Here are the individual files (.htaccess, sitemap.xml, index.php):
.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/index\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.my-domain.eu/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-domain.eu/$1 [L,R=301]

sitemap.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<url>
<loc>http://www.my-domain.eu/</loc>
<lastmod>2024-08-26</lastmod>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
</urlset>

index.php

<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.my-domain.eu/" />
<meta name="language" content="de">

How can I solve the problem or who can help me?
Thank you
Chris
Help -> Canonical Tag

Your redirects and canonical are for http. Should you not be using https? What domain have you registered with the Search Console?
